# PHP: How to use monolog to log to console (php://out)?

Tags: php, console, stdout, monolog

I just switched to monolog and wanted to log my message to the PHP console instead of a file. This might seem obvious for some people, but it took me a little while to figure out how to do that and I couldn't find a similar question/answer on SO.

The example on [Monolog's Github readme](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) only shows how to use a file:

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('path/to/your.log', Logger::WARNING)); // <<< uses a file

// add records to the log
$log->addWarning('Foo');
$log->addError('Bar');
```

But it doesn't state anywhere how messages can be logged to the console. After searching on Google, I landed either on a help page for Symfony or questions of people looking for a way to log to the browser console.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

The solution is rather simple. Since the example shows a `StreamHandler` it's possible to pass in a stream (instead of the path to a file). By default, everything that is echo'ed in PHP is written to [php://stdout / php://output](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) so we can simple use one of those as stream for the `StreamHandler`:

```
<?php

use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

// create a log channel
$log = new Logger('name');
$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('php://stdout', Logger::WARNING)); // <<< uses a stream

// add records to the log
$log->warning('Foo');
$log->error('Bar');
```

Hope this saves somebody some time :)

Comment: this works however i would like to know how to archive the both i.e show the output in the console AND write to a file ?

Comment: @mahen3d add another handler to do that for you (```$log->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('/path/to/log/file', Logger::NOTICE))```)

Answer (score 22):

Some extra details if you want to tweak the default message formatting at the same time:

```
use Monolog\Logger;
use Monolog\Formatter\LineFormatter;
use Monolog\Handler\StreamHandler;

$output = "[%datetime%] %channel%.%level_name%: %message%\n";
$formatter = new LineFormatter($output);

$streamHandler = new StreamHandler('php://stdout', Logger::DEBUG);
$streamHandler->setFormatter($formatter);

$logger = new Logger('LoggerName');
$logger->pushHandler($streamHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to print out during a web request you could also use `php://output`

```
$logger = new Logger('');
$logger->pushHandler(new StreamHandler('php://output', Logger::DEBUG));

$logger->debug('my message', ['var1', 'var2']);
```

As I dont think stdout works during web request.